# Looking for Proxy Server (like MapProxy) but for Vector/Feature Data

Tags: wfs, features, vector-tiles, feature-service, mapproxy

Currently, I'm using MapProxy to pull raster tiles from web services, cache those tiles locally, then serve them back out.  So MapProxy is acting as a performance enhancing proxy.

Is there any piece of software that can function similar to MapProxy, but for feature data, like Vector Tiles or WFS?

Comment: Do you have any solution for this?